# Incrementing a java.util.Date by one day

Tags: java, date

What is the correct way to increment a java.util.Date by one day.

I'm thinking something like

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(toDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        toDate = cal.getTime();
```

It doesn't 'feel' right.

Comment: this looks correct, I would not reuse `toDate` I would have a new variable called `nextDate`, `dayAfterToDate` or something more explicit and self explanatory

Comment: It looks bad because it looks like you are modifying a shared singleton value just to add a day to a date.  But the javadoc for getInstance() says "Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale." So it is actually a new Calendar that is retruned.  

Java 1.8 LocalDateTime is a much better implementation, but maybe this helps someone (else) doomed to tweak someone else's Java 1.6.

Answer (score 20):

That would work.

> It doesn't 'feel' right.

If it is the verbosity that bothers you, welcome to the Java date-time API :-)

Answer (score 19):

If you do not like the math in the solution from Tony Ennis

```
Date someDate = new Date(); // Or whatever
Date dayAfter = new Date(someDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis( 1 ));
```

But more or less since finding this Q/A, I have been using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), instead, and have recently switched to the new DateTime in Java 8 (which *inspired* by but not copied from Joda - thanks @BasilBourqueless for pointing this out).

#### Java 8

In Java 8, almost all time-based classes have a *.plusDays()* method making this task trivial:

```
LocalDateTime.now()  .plusDays(1);
LocalDate.now()      .plusDays(1);
ZonedDateTime.now()  .plusDays(1);
Duration.ofDays(1)   .plusDays(1);
Period.ofYears(1)    .plusDays(1);
OffsetTime.now()     .plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
OffsetDateTime.now() .plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
Instant.now()        .plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Java 8 also added classes and methods to interoperate between the (now) legacy Date and Calendar etc. and the new DateTime classes, which are most certainly the better choice for all new development.

Comment: Actually, the [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) found in Java 8 is inspired by but not based on [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, that's right.  Java Date APIs feel wrong quite often.  I recommend you try [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  It would be something like:

```
DateTime startDate = ...
DateTime endDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
```

or:

```
Instant start = ...
Instant end = start.plus(Days.days(1).toStandardDuration());
```

Comment: Absolutely!  I dislike date arithmetic in java.util.Date so much that on my current I isolated it into a set of 6-8 methods.  This was fine, but after I found Joda Time these methods became 1-2 liners *and* a couple even gained a bit in generality.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I do it:

```
Date someDate = new Date(); // Or whatever    
Date dayAfter = new Date(someDate.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000));
```

Where the math at the end converts a day's worth of seconds to milliseconds.

Comment: Why the -1?  The number of hours, minutes, and seconds is unlikely to change anytime soon.

Comment: for one thing, this doesn't take into account Calendar things like leap year and leap seconds and other minutia, this is why the equivilent methods on Date() are deprecated and Calendar, and GregorianCalendar exist in the first place. And your code doesn't handle daylight savings time either, naive at best, a source of endless thedailyWTF articles and bugs at worst.

Answer (score 4):

If Java 8 or Joda Time are not an option, you could always opt for Apache DateUtils:

```
DateUtils.addDays(myDate, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library makes it much more clean to work with dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date thisDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

Date dayAfter = new Date(thisDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis( 1 ));

Date dayBefore = new Date(thisDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis( -1 ));
```

Comment: It doesn’t take into account that a day may occasionally be 23 hours, 25 hours or some other length. Also I don’t understand why anyone would want to use the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` class in 2019.

Comment: someone develops or supports software  which is written on the old version of Java

Answer (score 0):

I am contributing the modern answer.

> It doesn't 'feel' right.

My suggestion is that why it doesn’t feel right is because it’s so verbose. Adding one day to a date is conceptually a simple thing to do and ought to have a simple representation in your program. The problem here is the poor design of the `Calendar` class: when you use it, your code needs to be this verbose. And you are correct: you should *not* use the poorly designed `Calendar` class. It’s long outdated. Using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, adding one day is simple, also in code:

```
    LocalDate toDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 28);
    LocalDate nextDate = toDate.plusDays(1);
    System.out.println("Incremented date is " + nextDate);
```

Output is:

> Incremented date is 2020-02-29

In case your need is for a different type than `LocalDate`, other java.time classes also have a `plusDays` method that you can use in the same way, as already shown in the answer by Ivin.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Answer by Ivin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812415/5772882)