# Play 2 Framework add days to Date

Tags: java, date, formatting

I got a simple Play template with the following structure.

`@(order : Order){
   <html><p> My Date @order.orderDate.format("dd'.'MM'.'yyyy")</p></html>
}`

I would like to add 2 Days to the printed Date direct in the template.

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you running on Java 8?  The best answer probably depends on this - they improved date-time support a lot.

Comment: Also, clue us in to the class of orderDate.  Without that, any answer is guesswork.

Comment: Yes, it us running on Java 8. The Class is a standard java.util.Date. Here is the declaration: public Date orderDate;

Comment: So the question is not specific either to Play or Java.

Comment: @cchantep - It's not Play, but it's Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incrementing a java.util.Date by one day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809119/incrementing-a-java-util-date-by-one-day)

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
            @{
            import java.util.Calendar

            val newOrderDate = Calendar.getInstance()
            newOrderDate.setTime(order.orderDate)

            newOrderDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)

            newOrderDate.getTime().format("dd'.'MM'.'yyyy")
        }
```